# datetime in Editable datatable showing incorrect date

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, model-view-controller, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm using .net MVC, and I use Editable Datatable to edit the data inline.

My Code is as below

```
`<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>
 Date
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
`

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">                       
            function SetTable(result) {
        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
            ajax: "/I/P",
            table: "#tblI",
            idSrc: 'I.IId',
            fields: [
                        { label: "Date", name: "I.Date", type: "datetime" },]
            [});
    </script>`
```

But the Date calandar shows wrong date under a week name.
For eg. March 16th 2016 comes under tuesday instead of wednesday.

[datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmEgO.png)

Comment: Did you check the timezone?

Comment: Yes. The problem was with Datatable Jquery file. The new version is working fine.